# Work in force field

Tags: calculus, integration

> Given two force fields as follows
>
> $$
> \vec F_1 = (yz^3 − 6xz^2)\vec e_x + 2xyz^3 \vec e_y + (3xy^2z^2 − 6x^2z) \vec e_z\\
> \vec F_2 = x^2yz \vec e_x − xyz^2 \vec e_z
> $$
> Calculate the work from point $A = (1, 1, 2)$ to point $B = (2, 2, 2)$ when moving under the influence of each of the two forces (separately) along two different paths (straight lines) as follows
>
> $C_1 :A →(2,1,2)→B$ and $C_2 :A →(1,2,2)→B$.

So, first I checked - the first force is a conservative force. Then I did parametrization of the line,
$(1,1,2)→(2,1,2)$, but it's just $ɑ(t)=(1,1,2)+t(1,0,0)$, if $t_1=0, t_2=1$
So do I just neglect the $(1,1,2)$ now?

I did $W = \int F·dr$ , but got that the answer is just $1$, because all the terms ended up being $0$ (because $y$ is $0$ and $z$ is $0$ in the parametrization).
Is that how I should solve it?

Comment: Please check the equations and rewrite them with MathJax. That way, there will be no misunderstadings when it comes to the notation and equations.

Comment: I typeset your math using MathJax. If I did any mistakes, it would probably be best if you corrected them yourself. Please consult what I have done, and [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not "just neglect the $(1,1,2)$".

When you travel along the straight segment from $A$ to $(2,1,2),$
the second two coordinates are $y = 1$ and $z = 2$ the entire time,
while $x$ ranges from $1$ to $2.$
I don't think that gives you a zero $x$ component in either of your force fields, does it?

Comment: So the parametrization would be (t+1,1,2)? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that should work. In fact it's just another way to write $(1,1,2)+t(1,0,0).$

Comment: But using (1,1,2)+t(1,0,0) how do I put it into the formula? I have to use there everything expressed by t (F(ɑ(t)*ɑ'(t))
ɑ'(t) being the derivative of ɑ with respect to t.

Comment: Use the notation that works for you. As I said, $(t+1,1,2)$ is fine. That's _because_ it's mathematically equivalent to the other notation, and the wonderful thing about that is you get to choose which notation to use.